# PostgreSQL user defined type member compare

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, composite-types

I have the following table definition:

```
 CREATE TYPE product_limit_type AS (
    product_code varchar(5),
    limit_type varchar(30),
    limit_value numeric(4,0)
);

CREATE TABLE rule_locks (
    session_id bigint,
    rule_id bigint,
    product_limit product_limit_type
);
```

When I execute the following query:

```
DELETE FROM rule_locks
WHERE (session_id=session_id_ AND product_limit.product_code=product_code_);
```

I get this error from the server:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "product_limit"
LINE 1: ...FROM rule_locks WHERE (session_id=session_id_ AND product_li...
                                                         ^
```

`session_id_` and `product_code_` are pre-initialized variables of corresponding types.

How is it supposed to erase/modify a row, whose cell member variable satisfies given condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be parentheses around the field's name to access its subfields, as in:

```
DELETE FROM rule_locks WHERE (session_id=session_id_
     AND (product_limit).product_code=product_code_);
```

See [Accessing Composite Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html#AEN7304) in the documentation.